# How can I create horizontal and vertically stacked images in Android?

Tags: android

I'm struggling trying to create simultaneously horizontal and vertically stacked images in Android. I've tried a bunch of different approaches but can't quite seem to get there. I'd upload an image of what I'm going for but don't have the stackoverflow points yet to do so :) so here's my code. Hoping you guys can help me stop banging my head against the wall. unless i'm still going about this completely wrong, seems my issue is in the last relative layout - am I not allowed to have a relative layout be to the right of a specific object in a LinearLayout? Also, how do i achieve this without overlap in my images?:

editing to show code with tableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:xlmns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1Buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<Button
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FILTER"
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Neighborhood?"
    android:id="@+id/neighborhoodButton"
    />

</TableRow>



<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableLayoutListing1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/listingImage1"
    android:src="@drawable/alex_room"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/listingImage2"
    android:src="@drawable/alex_room_two"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listingImage1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listingImage2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/listingImage3"
        android:src="@drawable/livingroom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just put it all in one relative layout? Linear layouts make things quick to code but for complex layouts, the relative layout is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest using a `LinaerLayout` if you want objects stacked in both horizontal and vertical positions. Using two `LinearLayouts` of two different orientations is also a bad idea.

The easier approach would be using a `TableLayout`, which can stack objects both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thanks Henry that solves a lot of it. Any suggestion for how to best make some cells larger than others? I've been trying to use layout_width = "0dp" and layout_weight= ".70" and for the other image in the row layout_weight=".30" but that seems to make the second image upper in the upper right corner of the row? Also, how do I best deal with a row where 1 image is effectively the size of 2 rows and I want 2 images stacked on the right? Right now the 3rd image appears below all of them?